# how to reuse a struct instance with Rust

Tags: rust

I am very new to `Rust`, coming from `python` programming language and i built the following logic below:

## main.rs

```
use library_system::Library;
use library_system::Book;

fn main() {
    let library = Library {
        name: String::from("Malcom X")
    };

    let book = Book {
        name: String::from("The Edge of AI"),
        author: String::from("Clement Adams"),
        released_date: String::from("06/01/2021"),
        library,
    };

    println!("library created: {:?}", library);
    println!("booked created {:?}", book);
}
```

## lib.rs

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Status {
    Free,
    Booked,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Library {
    pub name: String,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Book {
    pub name: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub released_date: String,
    pub library: Library,
}
```

For some reason, when i try to print the outcome of the codes above in the terminal i receive the message at compile time:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `library`
  --> src/main.rs:19:39
   |
6  |     let library = Library {
   |         ------- move occurs because `library` has type `Library`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
16 |         library,
   |         ------- value moved here
...
19 |     println!("library created: {:?}", library);
   |                                       ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

What is the appropriate way to solve this problem?

I tried to solve the problem doing:

```
let library_clone = library.clone();

println!("library created: {:?}", library_clone);
```

but now i am facing the following issue:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for struct `Library` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:33
   |
10 |     let library_clone = library.clone();
   |                                 ^^^^^ method not found in `Library`
```

Comment: Have `library` be a `&Library` so that it's a reference to a library instead of taking ownership of the library.

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-mutability-moving-and-borrowing-the-straight-dope/22166 This post was useful for me, when I encountered a similar problem.

Comment: @Samathingamajig The problem with that is that they would need to add a lifetime annotation. The easiest way to make this compile is to println the library before. This will of course become an issue once there's more than one book. In that case they can use a reference, as long as they don't mutate the library after creating the books.x

Answer (score 1):

Rust operates on a *single-ownership model*, which means that every value is owned uniquely by one place in your code at a time. By default, when you pass an argument to a function, you pass it *by value*, which means you pass full ownership rights to that function. A corollary is that, if you pass ownership to a function, you no longer have the right to do anything with that value. (Types that implement the `Copy` trait, such as numerical types, are exceptions to this, but your type isn't eligible for `Copy`)

If you want to let a function view your data without giving it full ownership, you should pass a reference to the function. Passing a reference allows the function to *borrow* your value without fully controlling it.

```
println!("library created: {:?}", &library);
```

Notice the `&` before `library`.

Also, since you mentioned `clone`, you should probably implement that for your structure. You can do so by hand

```
impl Clone for Library {
  fn clone(&self) -> Library {
    Library { name: self.name.clone() }
  }
}
```

But the pattern of "clone `self` by cloning all of its parts" is so common that the `Clone` trait has a `derive` macro. So you can just write

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Library {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `println` borrows all arguments already, so using `&library` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, assignment works differently than in Python or C++.  For many types in Rust, when you assign `var1` to `var2`, the value in `var1` is moved into `var2`, then `var1` is uninitialized and no longer contains the value.  Thereafter, the compiler will not let you use the uninitialized variable.

---

If you do this:

```
let s1 = String::from("hello");
let s2 = s1;

println!("{}, world!", s1);
```

You will get this error:

```
 --> src/main.rs
  |
2 |     let s1 = String::from("hello");
  |         -- move occurs because `s1` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     let s2 = s1;
  |              -- value moved here
4 |
5 |     println!("{}, world!", s1);
  |                            ^^ value borrowed here after move
  |
```

According to [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html), the reason for that error is because `s1` is a pointer to a spot in memory where a String is stored, and when you write:

```
let s2 = s1;
```

Rust copies the pointer into s2.  That leaves you with two pointers to the same spot in memory, and when `s1` and `s2` eventually go out of scope, Rust will free the memory pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, which will lead to the same memory being freed twice, which is known as a "double free" error.

To prevent the same memory from being freed twice, Rust immediately invalidates the `s1` pointer after you assign it to `s2`. That is known as ***a move***: the pointer has ***moved*** from one variable to the other.

***Borrowing*** is when you create a reference to another variable, i.e. a pointer to another variable, i.e. not a copy of the value in the variable, e.g. `&library`, which is normally not an error.

Your code is throwing the same error as the String example above, so it seems like something analogous is happening.  However, I searched around and variables which have been assigned a Struct do not contain pointers to some place in memory, so there is no "double free" issue.  Nevertheless, the following code throws the same "borrow after move" error:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Library {
    age: u16,
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = Library {age: 31};
    let _s2 = s1;

    println!("{:?}", s1);
}
```

error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s1`
  --> src/main.rs:10:22
   |
7  |     let s1 = Library {age: 31};
   |         -- move occurs because `s1` has type `Library`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
8  |     let _s2 = s1;
   |               -- value moved here
9  |
10 |     println!("{:?}", s1);
   |                      ^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
```

The error is saying that the value assigned to the s1 variable has been moved into the s2 variable, and thereafter `println!()` tries to use the s1 value (but it's not there anymore!).

As far as I can tell, the rule appears to be: if a value does not implement the Copy trait, then when you assign a variable containing the value to another variable, Rust will move the value and invalidate the first variable.

After doing some more research...."Programming Rust (2nd Edition)" p 85, simply states:

> In Rust, for most types, operations like assigning a value to a
> variable, passing it to a function, or returning from a function don't
> copy the value: they *move* it.  The source relinquishes ...
> the value to the destination and [the source] becomes uninitialized...
>
> You may be surprised that Rust would change the meaning of such
> fundamental operations; surely assignment is something that should be
> pretty well nailed down at this point in history.  However, if you look
> closely at how different languages have chosen to handle assignment,
> you'll see that there's actually significant variation from one school
> to the other.

The book explains how assignment works in Python with this code:

```
s = ["udon", "ramen", "soba"]
t = s
u = s
```

In the assignments `t = s` and `u = s`, Python copies the pointer in `s` into `t` and `u`, and increments the reference count for the list to 3.  Assignment is very efficient due to the fact that the list isn't copied. On the other hand, Python has to keep reference counts for the list, and only when the reference count drops to 0, i.e. when `s`, `t`, and `u` all drop out of scope, is the memory freed.  Reference counting and the attendant garbage collecting creates overhead, i.e. it slows down execution.

The book compares Python's assignment to C++.  Here's the C++ example used in the book:

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> s = {"udon", "ramen", "soba"};
vector<string> t = s;
vector<string> u = s;
```

The book says that the C++ assignments:

```
vector<string> t = s;
vector<string> u = s;
```

make copies of the vectors, and there ends up being three vectors in memory, collectively containing nine strings.  There is no need for reference counting and garbage collecting: when a variable goes out of scope, the memory containing its copy is freed.  However, making copies of values, especially large, complex values takes more time and more memory.

The book explains a similar Rust example:

```
let s = vec!["udon".to_string(), "ramen".to_string(), "soba".to_string()];
let t = s;
let u = s;
```

The initialization:

```
let t = s;
```

moves the vector from `s` into `t`.  The vector's elements stay just where they are in memory.  There are no reference counts to be adjusted, rather the memory taken up by the vector will be freed when `t` goes out of scope.  And, the compiler now considers `s` uninitialized.

> So what happens when we reach the initialization:
>
> ```
> let u = s;
> ```
>
> This would assign the uninitialized value `s` to `u`.  Rust prudently
> prohibits using uninitialized values, so the compiler rejects this
> code with the following error:
>
> [similar move error you got]

Back to your program.  You assigned the `library` variable to a field in your `book Struct`, hence Rust moved the value in the `library` variable into the field in the `book Struct` and immediately uninitialized the `library` variable.  Thereafter, the compiler won't let you use the uninitialized `library` variable: you get an error saying,

> Sorry, there used to be a value in this variable, but you moved the
> value into another variable, and now this variable is uninitialized.
> Then you subsequently tried to use this variable.  Don't do that!

What do you think happens in this code:

```
fn do_stuff(str: String) {
    println!("{} world", str);
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");  
    do_stuff(s); 
    
    println!("{}", s);  //<==** What happens here?
}
```

That should be pretty surprising for anyone coming from Python or C++!

Now, ***borrowing*** can be understood better.   Look at this example:

```
let s = vec!["udon".to_string(), "ramen".to_string(), "soba".to_string()];
let t = &s;
let u = &s;

println!("{}", s[0]);
println!("{}", t[1]);
println!("{}", u[2]);
```

output:

```
udon
ramen
soba
```

When you create a reference to a variable, e.g. `&s`, and you assign the reference to another variable nothing is moved.  Additionally, when `t` and `u` go out of scope, that doesn't free up the memory containing the vector:

```
let s = vec!["udon".to_string(), "ramen".to_string(), "soba".to_string()];

{
    let t = &s;
    let u = &s;

    println!("{}", s[0]);
    println!("{}", t[1]);
    println!("{}", u[2]);
}

println!("{}", s[0]);
```

output:

```
udon
ramen
soba
udon
```

It's only when `s` goes out of scope that the memory containing the vector is freed.