# Creating an alias for a variable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code in Rust (which will not compile but illustrates what I am after). For readability purposes, I would like to refer the same string with two different names so that the name of variables passed to a function match their real meaning. This can be "solved" if I clone `date_created` but then I'm needlessly copying data.

```rust
let date_created: String = utc_now_str();
let paste_state_date = date_created;

// ...

some_function( date_created, paste_state_date );
```

Is there an efficient idiomatic way to create this "second name" for the same variable?

Comment: Are you asking about ["What are references in Rust?"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) Remember that in Rust a "variable" is really just an owner of some data, and you can't have multiple owners of the same thing. You'll need a reference.

Comment: @tadman Thanks; I thought I understood that, but the following does not work because constructing the reference to the original borrows the original and so it seems I can't use both during the invocation of a function. Am I missing something really simple?
```
let str1 = ...;
let str2 = &str1;
my_func(str1, *str2);
```

Comment: When you pass a variable into a function, that function now "owns" that data, so any lingering references are a problem. To fix this, pass in a reference to that function, and alter the function to take a reference. You may find that if, say, you're used to C++ where references are pretty much inconsequential in terms of impact, you'll have to adjust your thinking here. In Rust references are significant and have specific meaning.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the function is in a library which does not accept a reference, so this seems unavoidable in that case. Thanks for your time on this basic question.

Comment: If it assumes ownership you'll need to make a copy, yes. Rust does have ways of keeping copies cheap, though, so keep that in mind. `Arc`, `Rc` and `Cow` are all useful tools here, depending on how much control you have over the interface.

Comment: It sounds very much like if you tried to do this in C++, the compiler would either copy the value for you, or you would invoke UB with a dangling reference. Simply put, Rust is catching potential UB that C++ would blindly allow.

Comment: In C++, at least to my mind, this function would have been something like `void some_function(const std::string&, const std::string&)` (or similar) and so the same string can safely be passed for both arguments. No copy, no UB, etc.

Comment: What is the exact library API you're having a problem with?

Comment: @BrandonPelfrey The equivalent of this signature in C++ is taking a reference in Rust, which you said the library doesn't.

Comment: From what you're describing, the equivalent C++ function would be `void some_function(const std::string, const std::string)`, which would silently copy the strings when you pass them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought I understood that, but the following does not work because
> constructing the reference to the original borrows the original and so
> it seems I can't use both during the invocation of a function. Am I
> missing something really simple?
>
> ```
> let str1 = ...; 
> let str2 = &str1;
> my_func(str1, *str2);
> ```

Are you familiar with how assignment in Rust works differently than assignment in C++?  Here's a simple example:

```
 let x = "hello".to_string();
 let y = x;
```

What do you expect the values of x and y to be after those statements execute in Rust?  Answer: x has no value, y has the value returned by "hello".to_string().  That's known as "a move" in Rust--in other words, assignment moves values from one variable to another.

In C++, if you write:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = x;
```

then  C++ will copy "hello" into y, which will leave you with two strings in memory.  You have to be aware of that difference when using assignment in Rust.

What can be confusing is that sometimes when you use assignment in Rust, the value *will* be copied.  For instance:

```
let x = 10;
let y = x;
```

After those statements execute in Rust, both x and y have the value 10.  In this case, Rust copies the value into y.  For simple values, like integer, float, byte, bool, and shared reference types, assignment copies the value into the new variable.

The reason the compiler won't let you write something like:

```
fn go(orig: String, orig_ref: &String) {
    println!("{orig}");
    println!("{orig_ref}");
}

fn main(){

    let pig = "pig".to_string();
    let pref = &pig;

    go(pig, pref);

}
```

is because calling the function involves an assignment:

```
 go(  pig     ,         pref);
       |                |
       V                V
fn go(orig: String, orig_ref: &String)  


    orig = pig      orig_ref = pref
```

Therefore, the String that was in `pig` is moved into `orig`, and `pig` becomes "uninitialized".  That leaves `pref` pointing to `pig`, which is no longer valid.  Rust was created to prevent C++ errors, like dangling pointers, so the compiler won't let you create a dangling pointer.

See the following for a more detailed description of how Python, C++, and Rust all take different approaches to the way assignment works:

[how to reuse a struct instance with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76151512/how-to-reuse-a-struct-instance-with-rust)

Because you seem to know C++, let's talk pointers. According to "Programming Rust (Revised 2nd edition)", a String type is a "fat" pointer: it consists of a length and a capacity, in addition to a pointer to some memory on the heap where the string is actually stored.  For instance, if you write:

```
   let pig = "hi".to_string();
```

then this is the situation:

[image]

The length is the actual length of the string and the capacity is how many total characters can fit in the allocated memory before Rust needs to allocate more memory for the string.  Like a regular pointer, a "fat" pointer is efficient to copy because it is only three "machine words" long--no matter how much memory is allocated on the heap.

Then if you write:

```
   let pref = &pig;
```

I think this is what happens:
[image]
`pref` doesn't point to the memory on the heap where the string is stored, rather `pref` points to the 3-word String on the stack.  Subsequently, if the String in `pig` is moved elsewhere, i.e. the 3-word fat pointer is copied to some other location on the stack and Rust "uninitializes" `pig`, then `pref` would become a dangling pointer.

Rust will automatically follow chains of pointers to pointers in order to retrieve the actual string, and that is why when you write:

```
 println!("{}", pref);
```

Rust will output the string rather than an address.